# Is it possible to use the "css-loader" without the "style-loader" in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

In some point of my application I want to receive a content of ".css" file with all "@import" and "url()/require()" processed. Previously, I was sure that "css-loader" do that transform, and "style-loader" generates a JavaScript code that injects resulting text file into web page. But it seems that I was all wrong. Where is no place in documentation that actually says **what** "css-loader" returns or what style-loaders takes as input. And it seems that "css-loader" returns not "processed css", but list of lists:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  entry: './foo.js',
  output: {path: '.', filename: '_foo.js'},
  module: {loaders: [{test: /\.css/, loader: 'css-loader'}]}
};
```

**foo.js**

```
console.log(require('./bar.css'));
```

**bar.css**

```
.bar { color: red; }
```

**shell**

```
$ webpack && node _foo.js
[ [ 0, '.bar {\n  color: red;\n}\n\n', '' ],
  toString: [Function: toString],
  i: [Function] ]
```

So, the question: is it possible to get actual post-processed css from the `css-loader`, or it's output are some internal things that are only intended to be used with a `style-loader` or other loaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`css-loader` returns the processed css. From what I can tell its output is an array of the processed modules: `[module.id, processedCss, '']`. In your example there is nothing to process, so it's unchanged. So let's have a look at an example that requires some processing:

For illustration purposes we enable css modules, so all classes will be replaced with a local hash:

```
{
  test: /\.css/,
  use: [{ loader: "css-loader", options: { modules: true } }]
}
```

**bar.css**

```
@import './imported.css';
body { color: green; }
.bar { color: red; }
```

**imported.css**

```
html { font-size: 16px; }
```

Now there is an `@import` that needs to be processed and also `.bar` which will be replaced with a hash. The output of this is:

```
[ [ 2, 'html { font-size: 16px; }\n', '' ],
  [ 1,
  'body { color: green; }\n._3mnMnh-NK57laCui8ulcdG { color: red; }\n',
  '' ],
  toString: [Function: toString],
  i: [Function],
  locals: { bar: '_3mnMnh-NK57laCui8ulcdG' } ]
```

Both files are separate modules that have been processed, and as you can see there is a `locals` property that maps the class names to the corresponding local hash, so you can easily refer to it in your code.

If you'd like to get just the resulting css, you can call `.toString()`, which gives us this output:

```
html { font-size: 16px; }
body { color: green; }
._3mnMnh-NK57laCui8ulcdG { color: red; }
```